# How to specify the python version gdb use

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I need to run gdb with python script, like ~/.gdb/qtprinters.py which require a high version
python.

our system gdb use default python version 2.7 and I installed a new gdb in my home with version 12.1 and also install an anaconda3 tool, but seems I cannot change the python version which gdb(12.1) use, when I configure to use a new python version with gdb, it will failed to make and compile as below:

```
./configure --with-python=/home/bob/tools/anaconda3/bin/python3.8 && make
```

The error message is like:

> configure: error: no usable python found at /home/bob/tools/anaconda3/bin/python
> CXXLD  gdbreplay
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:12137: configure-gdb] Error 1

but when configure to use the system default python version as below, the gdb(12.1) can be installed successfully as below:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python && make
```

Comment: I just found that do not use python in anaconda3 but python in other places, like with  this command, it can compile through  ./configure --with-python=/home/bob/python/3.8.7/bin/python